# why I cannot read data from plist?

Tags: ios, swift, plist

[image]
This is part my code. But `myDict` is `nil`. The filename is right.I already checked for many times.

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CatData", ofType: "plist") {
        myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
    if let dict = myDict {
        print("print something")
    }
```

Comment: can you show CatData.plist format?

Comment: The root of your plist isn't a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your plist is array of dictionary so try

```
    var myArray: NSArray?
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Categories", ofType: "plist") {
        myArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
    if let array = myArray {
        for item: AnyObject in array {
            if let item = item as? NSDictionary {
                if let categoryTitle = item["CategoryTitle"] as? NSString {
                    print("categoryTitle = ", categoryTitle)
                }
                if let imageNames = item["ImageNames"] as? NSArray {
                    print("imageNames = ", imageNames)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is an Array of Dictionary.

Comment: @beasone yes You can get plist content data in array then continue parse it

Answer (score 0):

Providing your file name is correct, and your plist has been added to the bundle:

You need to make sure your file is the type you're expecting.

For example. The root of your plist is an Array, and you're looking to get a Dictionary out of it.

So lets rewrite your code:

```
var myArray: Array? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CatData", ofType: "plist") {
        myArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
    } 
    if let array = myArray {
        print("print something")
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems my plist is an Array of dictionary. How could I get the data into an Array of dictionary ?

Comment: var dict: Array<Dictonary(String, Array)> like this ?

Comment: give me a few min, to make some changes

Comment: But I cannot just set myArray as type NSArray, because I need a variable as an Array of Dictionary.

Comment: So you're after a SWIFT Array full of SWIFT Dictionaries? So you want something like this [[String:AnyObject]]?

Comment: like: Array<Dictionary<String,Array<String>>> I think

Comment: Right, so you need to convert the NSArray to an Array. the `contentsOfFile` method only works on the NS classes. Try my edit.